How to set the key attribute of one specific element in vuejs3
In Vue3 (version 3.4.21), I have an "single" component in the middle of a list and I want to set a special key value for this element so that transitions work as expected.
<transition-group>
<template v-for="element in listOfElements" :key="element.id">
  <list-item-component />
  <single-component v-if="element.id == someVariable" key="uniqueText" />
</template>
</transition-group>

<single-component /> will be rendered only once because of the v-if condition.
In the example above, <single-component /> gets the key "{element.id}uniqueText" which is fine to be unique in the list yet when someVariable changes, the key changes too and the node is re-created as a new one. One of the side effect is that transitions are ugly in this context as two nodes are visible during the transition.
How can I override the default mechanism of Vue to have a immutable key in this context or how can I restructure my template so that the position of <single-component> slides smoothly amongs the <list-item-component /> depending on the value of someVariable?
Thanks

I ended up using the <component /> from vue (https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) to have a generic for loop where I can set the key manually:
<transition-group>
<component
    v-for="element in wrapper"
    :is="element.component"
    :key="element.key"
/>
</transition-group>

And in the script setup, I added a computed property:
<script setup>
import ListItemComponent from "@/xyz.vue";
import SingleComponent from "@/wxyz.vue";

const wrapper = computed(() => {
   let out = [];
   for (let elem of listOfElements) {
      out.push({
         component: ListItemComponent,
         key: elem.id
      })
      if (someVariable == elem.id) {
         out.push({
            component: SingleComponent,
            key: "static-unique-key"
         })
      }
   }
   return out;
})
</script>

It makes the code a bit messy but the transition when someVariable changes is smooth.
